# Implement Textbox in MVC Webgrid for item.Quantity with value on postback

Tags: asp.net-mvc, textbox, postback, webgrid

I'm not sure if this is entirely possible.

Currently I've managed to display a textbox for a certain column in a webgrid, but is it at 
all possible to have the value that it was changed to be part of the model when it is submitted back to the controller?

Is there perhaps another approach that this can be done?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, by making it an input of type "text", and placing it inside a form.  You can create a form within each row (in which case the postback would be a single record); or you could place the entire Webgrid inside a form.  The latter is trickier, because you have to get the naming correct for the inputs.  If your model is named "mycollection" and your textbox targets "prop1", for example, then your rows might look like this:

**Row 1**

```
<input type="text" name="mycollection[0].prop1" value="@item.prop1" />
```

**Row 2**

```
<input type="text" name="mycollection[1].prop1" value="@item.prop1" />
```

Etc.

This is not a complete answer, obviously, but I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, yeah that's what I thought, and have now managed to implement it like that, so atleast it comes back in the model on the postback, but for some reason now, the other properties in the collection or either null or empty, where before they had values in them. For Example collection has two properties StockValue, StockQuantity. StockValue had value of 259 on load, and now on postback has 0 in the model? Any Idea's?

Comment: The other fields have to be in the form if you want them to get posted back.  You could add them as inputs with type "hidden".

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ?

```
    var grid = new WebGrid(Model, canPage: true, rowsPerPage: 20);
    @grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "table", alternatingRowStyle: "alternate", headerStyle: "header",
    columns: grid.Columns(
       grid.Column(columnName: "name", header: "Name", canSort: true),
       grid.Column(format: @<span>@Html.TextBox("Age",@item.age)</span>   ),              
       grid.Column(" ", " ", format: @<a href="@Url.Action("AddAge", "People", new { id = item.id, ag = age })">Add age</a>),
```

And then you have

```
    public ActionResult AddAge(string id, int age = 1)
    {
        var peopleqry = db.People.Single(a => a.id== id);
        // do somehing with your age
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

Not sure if the Html.TextBox(... , *_*_) works.

I hope it helps.